# Vsphere Client Migrate option

Tags: hard-drive, vmdk

I want to convert an VMDK disk THICK into THIN...when i click in the Virtual machine with right button it should Appear MIGRATE option but it dont appear...someone know other method to conver HDD THICK in THIN

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the migrate option appear under commands? Where Power off, Suspend, reset, etc appears?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vmkfstools to convert disk format from thick to thin.
From the ESX/ESXi terminal you can change vmdk format with the following command:

```
vmkfstools -i vm01_1-flat.vmdk -d thin vm01THIN.vmdk
```

There is a detailed article on the topic http://networklessons.com/vmware/convert-vmware-esxi-thick-provisioned-disk-to-thin/